Running Gazebo simulation on a remote linux computer and access the GUI on another computer
I am trying to run a gazebo simulation on a more powerful remote headless linux server and access the GUI for that sim on another less powerful computer. I am currently using Gazebo Garden and Ubuntu 22.
My understanding from https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/architecture is that there are two processes, the backend server process and the frontend client process.
My question is: Can I run the gazebo backend server process on my powerful remote linux and run the gazebo client (on my less powerful linux computer (to access the GUI) (I also have a less powerful windows computer too).
And if the answer is yes - how would I do it?
I have read https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/headless_rendering.html However, from my understanding this would not allow me to access the GUI for gazebo.
I can see that gazebo classic had separate executables gzserver and gzclient in its documentation https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=quick_start#Clientandserverseparation , however it does not elaborate how they would be used if they were on separate computers.
Gazebo sim (the newer gazebo) can be run in headless as described in https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/headless_rendering.html however I do not see any way to connect a GUI to the headless simulation.
VNC is not an option with my remote linux server and if possible I would really like to avoid X11 if possible - but please let me know if this is the only way.

I see your edit of my answer has been rejected. Feel free to add your findings as a comment, they seemed useful for newbies ;)

Headless rendering has nothing to do with GUI. It specifies whether sensor renderers will use GLX (which requires a running X11 server, but doesn't display anything on it) or EGL (which does not require X11 server, thus called headless).
gz sim command has options -s (server only) and -g (GUI only). This is what you want.
Next, both computers need to be in the same LAN and have equal value of environment variable GZ_PARTITION.
